# Recursive function in F# that determines in a list of n elements of type int, the greater of two adjacent values

Tags: f#

I have recently started learning f# and I have a problem with a task like the one in the subject line.  I managed to solve this task but not using a recursive function. I have tried to convert my function to a recursive function but it does not work because in the function I create arrays which elements I then change. Please advise me how to convert my function to a recursive function or how else to perform this task.

```
let list = [8;4;3;3;5;9;-7]
let comp (a,b) = if a>b then a elif b = a then a else b  
let maks (b: _ list)  =
    let x = b.Length
    if x % 2 = 0 then
        let tab = Array.create ((x/2)) 0
        for i = 0 to (x/2)-1 do
            tab.[i] <- (comp(b.Item(2*i),b.Item(2*i+1))) 
        let newlist = tab |> Array.toList 
        newlist
    else
        let tab = Array.create (((x-1)/2)+1) 0
        tab.[(((x-1)/2))] <- b.Item(x-1)
        for i = 0 to ((x-1)/2)-1 do
            tab.[i] <- (comp(b.Item(2*i),b.Item(2*i+1)))
        let newlist = tab |> Array.toList 
        newlist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth noting that, if you were doing this not for learning purposes, there is a nice way of doing this using the `chunkBySize` function:

```
list 
|> List.chunkBySize 2
|> List.map (fun l -> comp(l.[0], l.[l.Length-1]))
```

This splits the list into chunks of size at most 2. For each chunk, you can then compare the first element with the last element and that is the result you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a homework question, I don't want to give away the answer, so consider this pseudocode solution instead:

- If the list contains at least two elements:

  - Answer a new list consisting of:

    - The greater of the first two elements, followed by
    - Recursively applying the function to the rest of the list
- Else the list contains less than two elements:

  - Answer the list unchanged

Hint: F#'s [pattern matching](https://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/07/f-pattern-matching-for-beginners-part-4-lists-and-recursion.html) ability makes this easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your guidance I managed to create the following function:

```
let rec maks2 (b: _ list,newlist: _ list,i:int) =
let x = b.Length
if x >= 2 then
    if x % 2 = 0 then
        if i < ((x/2)-1)+1 then
            let d = (porownaj(b.Item(2*i),b.Item(2*i+1))) 
            let list2 = d::newlist
            maks2(b,list2,i+1)
        else
        newlist
    else
        if i < ((x/2)-1)+1 then
            let d = (porownaj(b.Item(2*i),b.Item(2*i+1))) 
            let list2 = d::newlist
            maks2(b,list2,i+1)
        else
        let list3 = b.Item(x-1)::newlist
        list3
else
    b
```

The function works correctly, it takes as arguments list, empty list and index.
The only problem is that the returned list is reversed, i.e. values that should be at the end are at the beginning. How to add items to the end of the list?

Comment: Easiest way is to use `List.rev` in the end to reverse list

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching to match and check/extract lists in one step.A typical recursive function, would look like:

```
let rec adjGreater xs =
    match xs with
    | []         -> []
    | [x]        -> [x]
    | x::y::rest -> (if x >= y then x else y) :: adjGreater rest
```

It checks wether the list is empty, has one element, or has two elements and the remaining list in `rest`.

Then it builds a new list by either using `x` or `y` as the first element, and then compute the result of the remaing `rest` recursivly.

This is not tail-recursive. A tail-call optimized version would be, that instead of using the result of the recursive call. You would create a new list, and pass the computed valuke so far, to the recursive function. Usually this way, you want to create a inner recursive loop function.

As you only can add values to the top of a list, you then need to reverse the result of the recursive function like this:

```
let adjGreater xs =
    let rec loop xs result =
        match xs with
        | []         -> result
        | [x]        -> x :: result
        | x::y::rest -> loop rest ((if x >= y then x else y) :: result)
    List.rev (loop xs [])
```